# Not showing my custom api in wsdl(url) and web service list?

Tags: api, magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have created Api in my module, when I accessing through coding it is working fine, but in url (wsdl format) & web services list (Back-End) are not showing. If I give my custom Api to others, it should be in web services list because we will provide permissions for that. So, how can I configure the custom api in wsdl & web service list?

my code is:

local->Course->Mca->etc->api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <mca translate="title" module="mca">
                <model>mca/api</model>
                <title>MCA Student Resources</title>
                <methods>
                    <create translate="title" module="mca">
                    </create>
                </methods>
                <faults module="mca"><!-- module="mca" specifies the module which will be used for translation. -->
                    <data_invalid> <!-- if we get invalid input data for customers -->
                        <code>100</code >
                        <!-- we cannot know all the errors that can appear, their details can be found in error message for call -->
                        <message>Invalid Student data. Details in error message.</message>
                    </data_invalid>

                </faults>
            </mca>
        </resources>
    </api>
</config>
```

local->Course->Mca->Model->Api.php

```
<?php
class Course_Mca_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    public function create($stuData)
    {
        return $stuData . ' My Custom Student Message';
    }

    public function info($stuId)
    {
    }

    public function items($filters)
    {
    }

    public function update($stuId, $stuData)
    {
    }

    public function delete($stuId)
    {
    }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create an `wsdl.xml` in your Moules `etc` directory?

Answer (score 1):

To allow access to your api via the roles section on the of the "web services" section you will need to update your code to include the `<acl>` node in-between api and resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <mca translate="title" module="mca">
                    <model>mca/api</model>
                    <title>MCA Student Resources</title>
                    <methods>
                        <create translate="title" module="mca">
                        </create>
                    </methods>
                    <faults module="mca"><!-- module="mca" specifies the module which will be used for translation. -->
                        <data_invalid> <!-- if we get invalid input data for customers -->
                            <code>100</code >
                            <!-- we cannot know all the errors that can appear, their details can be found in error message for call -->
                            <message>Invalid Student data. Details in error message.</message>
                        </data_invalid>
                    </faults>
                </mca>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

Comment: I have updated my code, but it is not showing in web service list & wsdl(format).

Comment: how do you get this list of web services? the above code will allow you to give this as a role under "SOAP/XML-RPC - Roles"

Answer (score 0):

Create a file calles `app/code/local/Course/Mca/etc/wsdl.xml` and compare its contents with one of those in core.

```
find app/code/core/Mage -iname 'wsdl.xml'
```